# set RequestHandler to use XmlView by default

Tags: xml, cakephp, requesthandler, json-view

I'm using the Xml/Json views for an API.

Going to '/Api.json' or '/Api.xml' works fine, but I'd like it to default to the XmlView when posting to '/Api'

What's the most simple/best way get this done?

- Edit:
  As  Jelmer mentioned, just doing '$this->layout = "xml"' does the trick - they should mention this in the documentation.

Comment: In your `ApiController::beforeRender()` add `$this->layout = 'xml'` Or didn't I understand your question?

Comment: You could probably do some routing stuff to get this to work, but this would be very non-standard.  Most API calls use an extension (traditionally; there's no hard rule) because it's clearer for the programmer.  Why would you want to remove the extension?  These URLs don't appear in the browser address bar so I don't see the point of making them pretty?

Comment: This is also a public Api, and a conversion from an existing one.
So it's 'nice' having it default to xml.

Jelmer was right, doing '$this->layout = "xml"' does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real trick was this one liner, had to look at the api documentation and try a couple of things:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    if(empty($this->RequestHandler->request->params['ext'])) {
        $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml'); 
    }
}
```